# Need to clear up exactly how BEM works

Tags: css, html, bem

I don't understand how nesting works with the BEM methodology.

Let's say I have a div with `class="header"`.

A child div that can only work with header, I'll call `class="header__top"`

Now lets say `header__top` also has a child div, do I call it `class="header__top__logo-container"`

And if `header__top__logo-container` has a child, do I call it 
`header__top__logo-container__logo` or do I cal it `header__top__logo`

For reference here is my html

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__top">
    <div class="header__top__logo-container">
      <a class="header__top__logo-container__logo" href="/"><img src="./assets/logo.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="header__top__cta-container">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__bottom">

  </div>
</div>
```

I have been confused about this for months...

Comment: For reference, the [BEM](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/) (Block, Element, Modifier) methodology is a component-based approach to web development created by Yandex.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is somewhat subjective, but imo your layout could be broken into some logical blocks.

BEM recommends against nesting elements. So the solution is to nest blocks.

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__top">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="./assets/logo.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cta">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__bottom">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## BEM

**B**lock
**E**lement - block's child
**M**odifier - block's relative

The main advantage of using the BEM methodology is that we do not chain the selector and therefore avoid errors caused by selectors precedence.

### `.block__element`

Use `__` to chain elements. Let's say we want to have two types of default buttons in our website. One of them is used in the header and the other is used in the main content. Then we would have

```
<header class="header">
  <button class="header__button">Header Button</button>
</header>
<main class="main">
  <button class="main__button">Main Button</button>
</main>
```

In this case `block__element` notation allows us to differentiate between these buttons to which we can refer in the CSS with `.header__button` and `.main__button`.

### `.block--modifier`

Use `--` to modify an element. Now imagine that in main section apart from having default styles for a generic button we want to have specific styles for confirmation button and cancel button.

```
<button class="main__button">Default Button</button>
<button class="main__button main__button-confirmation">Confirmation Button</button>
<button class="main__button main__button--cancel">Cancel Button</button>
```

### Example

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #5C6BC0;
  height: 4em;
  padding: 0 1em;
  color: #FAFAFA;
 }
 
.header__logo {
  margin: 0
}

.header__button {
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.header__button--primary {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  border-color: #FAFAFA;
}

.header__button--primary:hover {
  background: #ef5350;
  color: #212121;
  border-color: #212121;
}

.header__button--secondary {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <h1 class="header__logo">Logo</h1>
  <nav class="header__navigation">
    <a href="#" class="header__button header__button--primary">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="header__button header__button--secondary">About</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```